# Geofield Map marker NODE ID

Tags: 7, google-maps

I have on Drupal 7 a Geofield Map Views that show a list of "Source" content on a Google Map.

I want to add on my marker on the map the information about the NID of the "Source" and I don't know how to do that.

[image]

The goal is to have my map and when I click on the marker, I get back the ID of the node and scroll down on the page to show the information about this Source.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a relationship, "Content" and make it available in fields.

If you can provide more details regarding your content type, I can provide a better answer.